# Value at position 1 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a class

Tags: angular, web-component, angular10

I'm pretty new to angular. I don't really understand this error.
I tried googling the error (like every noob). Whenever I add a new component, doesn't recognize it as a component.

I also have restricted access since it is a company laptop.

The following is the error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:4510:22 - error NG1010: Value at position 1 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a class
      Value is a reference to 'NgModule'.

    4510 export declare const NgModule: NgModuleDecorator;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:4510:22
        4510 export declare const NgModule: NgModuleDecorator;
                                  ~~~~~~~~
        Reference is declared here.
```

Here is my `ng --version`

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 12.18.2
OS: win32 x64



Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1002.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         10.2.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          10.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1002.0 (cli-only)
```

Edit:
Here is the image [(This is the 2nd image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7vqV.jpg)

Edit 3: After changes suggested by Mike. I have the same error when I add a new component as I did when I started. Here is a pic

[Error due to Status bar component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFZtn.jpg)

The only thing in my **status-bar.component.html**

```
<img src="file://C:/Users/shouryadwivedi/Desktop/Work/angular-screens/ic_stat_battery_full">
```

Comment: can you share the contents of your module file?

Comment: Please share some screenshot to support you better. My strong feeling is that there is some syntax error, but the picture can be clearer once contents are put along with your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have attached my app.module.ts. If you need anything else, I'll be happy to give it to you. :)

Comment: Can you please attach the code of 'AppComponent'?

Comment: I have attached the app.component.ts image here.

Comment: From what I can see in your `app.module.ts` you're importing `NgModule` which isn't nescessary. Simply remove it from the `imports` array and it should work.

Comment: As a sidenote, please don't remove information after you've edited your post as it might be (and in this case was) crucial to solving the problem.

Comment: My apologies for removing the first photo. I did what you said. I now have a new error which I have put in the Edit 3.

Comment: Make sure you have the `@Component` decorator above the class declarations and add the `app-status-bar` component to either the `declarations` array of `AppModule` or if `app-status-bar` is inside another module, add that module to the `imports` array of `AppModule`